# Installed 12.04 from CD problems with compiz-core - wont continue - just

Tags: 12.04, installation

Installed 12.04 from CD to clean hard drive but on first boot up says problems with compiz-core. Clicked continue with it not installed. After I sent info for help; it came back with some packages are not up to date. Said I need to update compiz-core and libylib2.0-0

Cancelled the process to send info (after second time) but it wont cancel and it wont load the desktop. What do I do now?

Right click will let me create a new folder/document or organise desktop by name etc but I cannot see the usual system bar or left menu items. Is there a way to load the terminal and reload the desktop. If this was windows I'd use cntrl alt delete and run explorer to fix the desktop.

Comment: OK I've found I can access ALL SETTINGS via the right click to change desktop background and now using overview I'm running UPDATE. Hopefully that might fix the 'no desktop showing' problem.

Comment: NO.All updates done. after restart still no top bar or menu items on left. So cannot use the system
Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I am still searching for this answer myself. For the time being on the login page before you enter your password and boot into Ubuntu, click on the Ubuntu symbol and there should be two options, "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu 2D". If you pick the 2D option then you can see everything in a less graphical mode. Still looks great and runs faster than Windows!

I'll update if I find out how to fix the compiz-core and libglib packages.

Answer (score 0):

That answer helped as far as it went.  Once I logged in using Ubuntu 2D, I went to system settings and checked for upgrades.  Apparently I had not installed upgrades when I installed the system.  Once I installed system upgrades through an internet connection, I was able to tun Ubuntu normally.

Look to see if you have installed system upgrades once you log in under 2D.

This is good for me, as I am recovering an older box that still has some life left.